# Get the days between two date saperated by weeks

Tags: php, date

how to find week start date and end date between
Two dates `10-08-2016 and 25-08-2016`

```
array['10-08-2016','16-08-2016'],array['17-08-2016','23-08-2016']
```

Comment: What is your trial on this? There are lots of resources already available in SO for this situation.

Comment: i have no idea how to solve it

Comment: Use `DateTime` and `diff`, this question has been answered a lot on stackoverflow. And all over the web for that matter.

Comment: @Praveen do you want the grouping of 7 days between these two dates `10-08-2016 and 25-08-2016` or want to find next monday after 10-08-2016 ?? As week starts on 15-08-16 after 10-08-16

Comment: @manjeet: I want all the monday between two dates

Comment: hiii @Praveen I've added a solution for you, check my answer and sorry I was busy that's why it's very late for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by loop through the date, find the day on each date and if it is Monday then push it into the array, like below:

```
$date = '10-08-2016';
$end_date = '25-08-2016';

$mondays = array();
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $day = date("l", strtotime($date));
    if($day == 'Monday')
    {
        $mondays[] = $date;
    }   
    $date = date ("d-m-Y", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}
print_r($mondays);
```

This will give you :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 15-08-2016
    [1] => 22-08-2016
)
```